# Conflict while importing com.google.protobuf.Timestamp in two proto files

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

**Problem**: The messages are shown as buffer type in confluent cloud ui for a topic whose schema (.proto) imports two other schema's (.proto) having a import of "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto".

I have three .proto files - a.proto, b.proto, c.proto.

a.proto and b.proto have timestamp dependency of google and is imported using the statement - `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto".

c.proto have dependency on a.proto and b.proto.

**Observations**:
Production and consumption of messages are fine, only that the messages are shown in byte array in confluent UI.

Once I remove the google/protobuf/timestamp dependency from any one of the proto files (a.proto or b.proto), messages are shown in json format on confluent ui.

Any help / suggestions for this issue ?